# How to keep partial view from overlapping content on main view page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a button in my view which, when clicked, displays the contents of a partial view.  Each time the user clicks the button, the content of the partial view is added.  This works, however, the main view does not bump down in order to allow room for the fields from the partial view.  So, after the second click, the fields from the partial view overlap  the main view's content.
I have tried adding an event on the button click which appends line break tags to the div where the partial view will appear, but that isn't moving the page content down.

How do I bump down the content in the main view?

[image: overlap]

Jquery:

```
$('#btn-add-employment').click(function () {
            var num = parseInt($('#employer-count').val());
            if ((num+1) > 3) {
                $('#employer-limit').text("Limit of 3 employers");
            } else {
                $('#employer-count').val(num + 1);
                $('#employer-limit').empty();
                var id = 0;  //set to 0 because for now, appicant record has not been created yet.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("AddEmploymentHistory")",
                    data: { ApplicantID: id, RecordNum: (num+1) },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#employment-history_' + (num+1)).html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn-add-employment">Add Employer</button>
                <span id="employer-limit"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="employer-count" value="0" />
                <div id="employment-history_1"></div>
                <div id="employment-history_2"></div>
                <div id="employment-history_3"></div>
```

Comment: i think problem is related to your css file or maby missing tag from AddEmploymentHistory action. check for heights in css. or availability, education etc container position absoulute

Comment: AddEmploymentHistory action just returns the partial view.  I'm not very good with css -- what element should I set the height on?

Comment: check for <button ... parent div has heigh

Comment: ok, I think I have the right idea now.  I'll post my final solution once I have it worked out further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I modified the jquery to find the current height value for the section, and then add to the height in order to make more space for the fields from the partial view.  The total height of the section with the newly added partial view is it's current height, plus the original height.  I don't save the original height, so it must be calculated using the number of partial views that have been added.

```
$('#btn-add-employment').click(function () {
            var num = parseInt($('#employer-count').val());
            if ((num+1) > 3) {
                $('#employer-limit').text("Limit of 3 employers");
            } else {
                $('#employer-count').val(num + 1);
                $('#employer-limit').empty();
                //adjust height on panel   <<< NEW STUFF
                var newheight = parseInt($('#collapseTwo').css('height').replace("px", "")) / (num + 1) + parseInt($('#collapseTwo').css('height').replace("px", ""));
                $('#collapseTwo').css("height", newheight);

                var id = 0;  //set to 0 because for now, appicant record has not been created yet.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("AddEmploymentHistory")",
                    data: { ApplicantID: id, RecordNum: (num+1) },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#employment-history_' + (num+1)).html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```